# Flask redirect url with anchor

Tags: python, flask, anchor

I have some problem with redirecting with anchors from python code.

My code:

```
func():
    ...
    redirect(url_for('my_view', param=param, _anchor='my_anchor'))
```

This redirect didn't redirect me to #my_anchor.

In template link like:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('my_view', param=param, _anchor='my_anchor') }}"></a>
```

works good... May be problem in flask function "redirect".

How I can use redirect with anchors in Flask?

Flask version 0.10.x

Comment: It works for me without the hash in ``_anchor``.

Comment: Markus, sorry, I use it without hash too... my mistake

Comment: Have you used a tool like Firebug or the built-in developer tools Chrome to see the exact HTTP that is happening? When you are being redirected, what URL ARE you being redirected to? Also, are you actually _returning_ the result of the `redirect()` function, or just calling the function? If you could provide a short example that illustrates your problem it would be easier for us to figure out.

Comment: I just wrote a [quick test](https://gist.github.com/markhildreth/8829451) and was not able to reproduce this. In this test, when I go to `/one`, I'm redirected to `/two#blah` and brought to the bottom of the page as expected.

Comment: What says curl? For example `curl -IL http://localhost:5000/test`

Comment: It work when I redirect from main file. But when I try to use this redirect from my included module it doesn't work.

I get just redirect to link without anchor.

Answer (score 21):

if your goal is to be redirected to a page with an anchor preselected in the url I think the problem may be connected to the function you have passed in the 'url_for'. Below is my attempt to do what you described.

**views.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


@app.route('/myredirect')
def my_redirect():
    return redirect(url_for('hello_world',_anchor='my_anchor'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This does not need a template, as as soon as you hit /myredirect you are redirected to / with anchor #my_anchor

After you get your views started with `$ python views.py` and navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5000/myredirect you end up on http://127.0.0.1:5000/#my_anchor

Comment: `_anchor='my_anchor'` is spot on.  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 3):

A short and simple way of doing this is

```
return redirect(url_for('hello_world') + '#my_anchor')
```

instead of

```
return redirect(url_for('hello_world',_anchor='my_anchor'))
```

which works because `url_for` returns a string for the endpoint.