# 301 Redirecting an old URL to a new one with Flask

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I recently changed the format of my URL's to have better readability and SEO. However, this will break my current URL's. So I want to redirect them in flask.

My question is similar to this one here:
[Redirecting an old URL to a new one with Flask micro-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789462/redirecting-an-old-url-to-a-new-one-with-flask-micro-framework)

However, the provided answer gave this:

```
redirect_urls = {
    '/article/old-url': '/article/new-url/id',
    '/article/old-url-2': '/article/new-url-2/id',
    '/article/old-url-3': '/article/new-url-3/id',
    ...
}

def redirect_url():
    return redirect(redirect_urls[request.url], 301)

for url in redirect_urls:
    app.add_url_rule(url, url, redirect_url)
```

The problem is, the code gives a 500 error code.

KeyError: '/article/old-url'

**Edit:**

Full traceback error:

```
Exception on /article/old-url [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/*****/mysite/flask_app.py", line 77, in redirect_url
    return redirect(redirect_urls[request.url], 301)
KeyError: 'https://www.example.com/article/old-url'
```

Comment: You just have to add an other `route` decorator to your views.

Comment: 6 months later and still need this to be answered :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it looks like this issue,

```
  File "/home/*****/mysite/flask_app.py", line 77, in redirect_url
    return redirect(redirect_urls[request.url], 301)
KeyError: 'https://www.example.com/article/old-url'
```

is caused because the following dictionary

```
redirect_urls = {
    '/article/old-url': '/article/new-url/id',
    '/article/old-url-2': '/article/new-url-2/id',
    '/article/old-url-3': '/article/new-url-3/id',
    ...
}
```

only has the child path.

To resolve this, one approach you can take is

```
BASE_URL = 'https://www.example.com'
return redirect(redirect_urls[request.url.replace(BASE_URL, '')], 301)
```

This will end up performing the following which is in the dictionary `redirect_urls`.

```
return redirect(redirect_urls['/article/old-url'], 301)
```

Answer (score 0):

as wrote Klaus above just add @route decorator to your methods like:

```
@app.route('/article/old-url', methods=['GET'])
def redirect_url():
    return redirect(redirect_urls[request.url], 301)
```

Comment: Also, I need a way to redirect multiple URL's not just the one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed it.

```
@app.before_request
def check_page():
    dict_of_pages = {
        '/page1/': '/page/1'
    }
    url = request.full_path.strip('?') 
    if url in dict_of_pages.keys():
        return redirect(dict_of_pages.get(url), code=301)

    pass
```